# HTML CSS : Taking CDN SVG Pictures and Converting them to PNG

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, svg

We are developing an ASP MVC Web Project. The team is taking icons from Google Materials IO and converting them to Png files (customizing them).
Is there any affects of this? We were accessing items from a CDN, now they have to be called with internal library from server (which maybe slower).

Additionally, I thought SVG is best option. 
Are there any negative consequences of conducting this, or nothing to worry about?

What if we customized the SVGs and resaved as new SVGs? would this alleviate any issues for the library?

https://material.io/tools/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with directly calling CDN to a header as below?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
```

Call icon as like below:

```
<i class="material-icons">
account_balance
</i>
```

You can change color at any time using color property.